# Extracting and sorting Data from a list- find the highest value

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, extract

I created a `table` and set it as a data frame. The first four variables are factors while the last four(fare, tax, comm, net) are numbers. I need to find which TA(travel agent) has sold the most tickets. How can I print the name along the max result? ex: 3300 ,pay more. In addition, in this table I have two variables (3300 and 3303) with the highest ticket amount (4)  Is R choose the first highest variable?. can I present all results? meaning: 3300 pay more 4   3303 pay by ticket 4.

```
 IATA          NAME TICKET_NUM            PAX FARE TAX COMM
1  3300      pay more        700     john cohen   10 1.1    2
2  3300      pay more        701     james levy   11 1.2    2
3  3300      pay more        702 jonathan arbel   12 1.2    3
4  3300      pay more        703      gil matan    9 1.0    2
5  3301      you pay         704      ron natan   19 2.0    6
6  3301      you pay         705    don horvitz   18 2.0    6
7  3302 pay by ticket        706  lutter kaplan    9 1.2    0
8  3303         enjoy        707   lutter omega   12 1.2    0
9  3303         enjoy        708   graig daniel   14 1.3    1
10 3303         enjoy        730 orly rotenberg   15 1.0    1
11 3303         enjoy        731     yohan bach   12 1.0    1
```

Comment: Text columns containing spaces are harder to input to R.  Please give this data in a machine-readable format (e.g., using `dput(head(x))`).  Also, I do not see a `net` column in your data.  And which column contains the TA?

Comment: IATA is a factor and its the travel agent ID number, name is the travel agent name. the net is the 8 column, seems like it wasn't entered when someone corrected the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NAME` is the travel agent name and `x` is the data, you can use `aggregate` to get the sums for each agent:

```
agg <- aggregate(FARE ~ IATA, data=x, FUN=sum)
```

Then sort and take the top element:

```
top_agent <- agg[order(agg$FARE, decreasing=TRUE),][1,] # Does not account for ties!
```

Edited to add:  I think I misread your question.  If you want to know how many tickets each agent sold rather than the total value of tickets, you can count them easily with `aggregate`.  This is easily accomplished by adding a ticket count to each row, and taking the sum of number of tickets.  There is one ticket per row:

```
x$tickets <- 1
```

And this aggregate gives the number of tickets per agent:

```
agg <- aggregate(tickets ~ IATA, data=x, FUN=length) # Equivalently, FUN=sum
```

The top agent here is given by a very similar computation:

```
top_agent <- agg[order(agg$tockets, decreasing=TRUE),][1,] # Still does not account for ties.
```

Then all activity by this agent is given by:

```
x[x$IATA == top_agent,]
```

Comment: It worked with the fare but I need to aggregate the number of tickets for each agent. for example 3300 pay more 4  3301 you pay 2. this function only work with numbers not with factors. any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for the IATA number and the aggregation but the travel agent name should also appear.when I tried to enter it to the function I get an error message